# Oracle Orion: How I can install orion separately without installing DB server

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to install orion without installing 11g DB server?
I want to run the test through a proxy server which doesn't have any DB server installed in actual. I want to run orion through this proxy server.

Answer (score 3):

Orion is distributed as part of a database / grid installation, but it is possible to copy it from an existing Oracle installation. It should be from the same platform - e.g. from Solaris on SPARC to Solaris on SPARC. All you need is the 'orion' binary and some libraries from the $ORACLE_HOME/lib directory.

You can find out which libraries you need by using 'ldd' on the executable file. Some of the linked libraries will be in */usr/lib/* or some other system directory. The rest will be in *$ORACLE_HOME/lib*.

Since your question is tagged as 12c, I'll post an example from a 12c installation from Solaris on SPARC (because I use that OS):

```
$ ldd ./orion | grep u01
libclntsh.so.12.1 =>     /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
libclntshcore.so.12.1 =>         /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1
libnnz12.so =>   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib/libnnz12.so
libcell12.so =>  /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib/libcell12.so
libskgxp12.so =>         /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib/libskgxp12.so
libmql1.so =>    /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib/libmql1.so
libipc1.so =>    /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib/libipc1.so
libons.so =>     /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/lib/libons.so

**the other libraries are in system folders and should already be installed on the other system**
```

After you copy the binary and libraries to the other machine you need to set the *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* environment variable to point to the directory with the libraries, so that the executable will be able to find them. Here is an example with Orion taken from 11g installation:

```
# pwd
/root/orion
# ls ./bin
orion
# ls ./lib/
libcell11.so       libclntsh.so.11.1  libnnz11.so        libskgxp11.so
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/root/orion/lib
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihail I will definitely try this out and let you know if it works.